# Surface light flickering on android devices

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, shader, light

I have a problem with surface light flickering on android devices. I have tried everything I found online including changing near/far clipping planes of the camera, changing some quality settings like cascade shadows, turning shadows off/on, limiting to just one light source but I always get this problem. Everything looks OK in the editor.

Models in my game are made of multiple smaller 3d objects and it is always few of them that get this glitch.

This is how it looks:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to publish the models you use? It's hard to diagnose a problem that we can not reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You say that your models are made from multiple smaller models. Are you sure this is a lighting issue and not a z-fighting issue?

This can happen when two planes are in the exact same place, and which one is in the front can randomly change from frame to frame giving a flickering effect.

[I could not find a credible Unity source explaining this issue, but here's a link to the Wikipedia on Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting)

As far as I know the only solution is to change your models to make sure the overlapping doesn't happen. Either my moving one of the planes down or deleting one of them.

Comment: Hi, thank you but this is not a Z-fighting issue. Z-fighting would most likely occur in editor and they models were checked for this.

Comment: Interesting, do you have any baked lights in the scene?

Comment: I don't have baked lights in this scene and the other scene with baked lights works fine. It seems that something is wrong with the lights in that specific scene. I will do more tests and come back here with the answer if I find it. I hoped somebody had the same problem already.

Comment: I've never encountered it myself. And if it's not zfighting or a light map issue it's hard to say what this could be. Are you sure the normals of the models are correct?